# Define a Policykit action for Upstart

Tags: 10.04, udev, dbus, policykit

I'm trying to get some user to start, stop and reload services by using the udev Upstart interface. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.

I created the file /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job.policy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1.0/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>
  <vendor>UXITIC</vendor>
  <vendor_url>http://citius.usc.es/</vendor_url>
  <icon_name>gdm</icon_name>

  <action id="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job.Stop">
    <_description>Stops a service</_description>
    <_message>Privileges are required to stop a service.</_message>
    <defaults>
      <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
    </defaults>
  </action>
</policyconfig>
```

And also the corresponding authority file /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-allow-users-to-start-and-stop-services.pkla

```
[Stop services]
Identity=unix-user:jorge
Action=com.ubuntu.Upstart_0.6.Job.Stop
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=auth_self
```

But when I try to stop a service, I get Access Denied :(

```
jorge$ dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=com.ubuntu.Upstart /com/ubuntu/Upstart/jobs/ssh com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job.Stop array:string:'' boolean:true
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.452" (uid=1021 pid=28234 comm="dbus-send) interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init"))
```

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: As @EricCarvalho points out this question is abandoned however that can't be a VTC reason as discussed recently here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17094/can-we-merge-these-three-qas-about-abandoned-questions-on-main. This question is about Ubuntu 10.04 which hit EOL on April 30 2015.  However as link points out we can't close as EOL even if it has zero answers. Therefore as per link VTC as not reproducible.